# Retrieving Data from database to JTable in java

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, sqldatatypes

I want to fetch some data from a database and display it in a [`JTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html). But this code is not working - it compiled successfully but doesn't give any output. What could be the issue? I'm new to Java, so please explain in detail.

```
try
{
    DefaultTableModel dtm=new DefaultTableModel();
    dtm.addColumn("RegNo");
    dtm.addColumn("Student Name");
    dtm.addColumn("Group Name");
    dtm.addColumn("College");
    dtm.addColumn("Phone No");
    dtm.addColumn("Events");
    dtm.addColumn("Event Category");
    dtm.addColumn("Amounts");
    String str="select * from robomaze;";
    ResultSet rs=DBConnect.st.executeQuery(str);
    int r=0,c=0;
    while(rs.next())
    {
        Class cTypes[]= {String.class,String.class,String.class,String.class,BigInteger.class,String.class,String.class,Integer.class};
        dtm.addRow(cTypes);
        c=0;
       dtm.setValueAt(rs.getInt(1), r, c);
         c++;
          dtm.setValueAt(rs.getInt(2), r, c);
         c++;
          dtm.setValueAt(rs.getInt(3), r, c);
          c++;
          dtm.setValueAt(rs.getInt(4), r, c);
          c++;
          dtm.setValueAt(rs.getInt(5), r, c);
          c++;
          dtm.setValueAt(rs.getInt(6), r, c);
          c++;
          dtm.setValueAt(rs.getInt(7), r, c);
          c++;
          dtm.setValueAt(rs.getInt(8), r, c);
          r++;
    }
    jtable1.setModel(dtm);
    DBConnect.con.close();

}catch(Exception en)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, en);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given....

```
dtm.addColumn("RegNo");
dtm.addColumn("Student Name");
dtm.addColumn("Group Name");
dtm.addColumn("College");
dtm.addColumn("Phone No");
dtm.addColumn("Events");
dtm.addColumn("Event Category");
dtm.addColumn("Amounts");
```

and...

```
Class cTypes[]= {String.class,String.class,String.class,String.class,BigInteger.class,String.class,String.class,Integer.class};
```

it is unlikely that using `getInt` for each column value is going to work, instead, you might need to use something more like...

```
while (rs.next()) {
    Object[] rowData = new Object[8];
    rowData[0] = rs.getString(1);
    rowData[1] = rs.getString(2);
    rowData[2] = rs.getString(3);
    rowData[3] = rs.getString(4);
    rowData[4] = rs.getInt(5);
    rowData[5] = rs.getString(6);
    rowData[6] = rs.getString(7);
    rowData[7] = rs.getInt(8);
    dtm.addRow(rowData);
}
```

Comment: In your code it shows java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: It doesn't showing any particular line. It only shows java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Use `en.printStackTrace();` to get a stack trace of the exception, which will provide the line number from which the problem originates from

Comment: ava.lang.NullPointerException
 at Dispaly.btnRetrieveActionPerformed(Dispaly.java:122)
 at Dispaly.access$000(Dispaly.java:17)
 at Dispaly$1.actionPerformed(Dispaly.java:56)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)

Comment: What does line 122 of `Dispaly.java` say?

Comment: String str="select * from robowar;";

Comment: Well, that's not my code, and I can't see why that would generate a `NullPointerException`, I suggest you might be running against some dirty code. Try doing a clean and build and run it again